# Is it correct to say "I wasn't finished"?

Tags: passive-voice, past-simple

I can realize that (was/were + p.p) is simple past passive ,But in this case (I wasn't finished) I can't realize to be the object ,How can I be finished , What does that mean ?

When I studied simple past passive, objects were things that the verbs can be done on it , like : apples can be eaten (The apple was eaten by someone) ,Or keys can be stolen (The key was stolen by someone).

I heard this sentence in term of that you have been interrupted ,and you haven't finished yet.

Can anyone explain this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's correct to say that.

The form is identical to *was + past participle,* but it is not a passive construction.

*Finished* is an adjective here, formed from the past participle.

See https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/finished

*Finished* is a state that describes the subject just like *hungry* in *I was hungry.*

See, for additional explanation:

www.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice#Stative_and_adjectival_uses